# Swiftui expand Vstack to cover remaining space

Tags: swiftui

I have a login screen in which I want to cover VStack whole white space which is remaining. I have 2 Vstack If I give Spacer to second one its not working.

My code

```
struct loginView: View {
    @State private var stringOfTextField: String = String()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [Color("primarycolor"), Color("secondarycolor")],
                           startPoint: .top,
                           endPoint: .center).ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack() {
                
                Text("Login").foregroundColor(.white).font(
                    .system(size: 18)
                    
                )
                
                Image("logo")
                Spacer()
            }
            VStack{
                TextField("Enter Email", text: $stringOfTextField)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).strokeBorder(Color.gray, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.0)))
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                TextField("Enter Password", text: $stringOfTextField)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).strokeBorder(Color.gray, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.0)))
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                Text("Forgot Password ?")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("sign up bin tapped")
                }) {
                    Text("SIGN IN")
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .stroke(Color("secondarycolor"), lineWidth: 1)
                        )
                }
                .background(Color("secondarycolor"))
                .cornerRadius(25)
                
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 60)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(30)
            
        }
  
    }
}
```

I try to add spacer in Vstack But its not working maybe due to Zstack. Its going on top if I give Spacer() to VStack

Comment: Attach a screenshot of what it looks like, and how u want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understood what you are trying to achieve, just please next time post a *complete* minimal reproducible example, replacing the custom colours and images.

You can keep the logo visible and cover the bottom area with 4 changes:

1. Wrap your current `VStack` with a new one; you need this to add a `Spacer()` that will keep the logo visible.
2. Add a `Spacer()` at the top of the new `VStack`, right before the existing one
3. Add a `Spacer()` at the *bottom* of the *existing* `VStack`
4. Add the `.ignoreSafeArea()` modifier to the `ZStack`

Here's the code:

```
ZStack {
    LinearGradient(colors: [.primary, .secondary],
                   startPoint: .top,
                   endPoint: .center).ignoresSafeArea()
    VStack() {
        
        Text("Login").foregroundColor(.white).font(
        // ... rest of the code
    }
    
    // 1) New VStack around the first one
    VStack {
        
        // 2) Spacer() before the existing VStack with minimum length, to keep the logo visible
        Spacer(minLength: 200)
        
        
        VStack{
            
            TextField("Enter Email", text: $stringOfTextField)

            // ... rest of the code

            .cornerRadius(25)
            
            // 3) New Spacer() at the bottom of the existing VStack
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 60)
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(30)
    }
    
}

// 4) Add this modifier to the ZStack
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: [.bottom])
```